# What does „stocks of things, recent stuff” mean?

Tags: phrases, idioms, slang, idiom-meaning

My friend has a problem with the phrase in the title. We’re both non-natives of English and despite my advanced level I’ve never seen such a phrase. It was said by a bilingual child while telling about a situation/story of a boy who was teased by other children (?) after a football match in which he scored 5 goals.
Can anyone explain me this in more straightforward, descriptive way so I can translate it more easily to my friend?

Comment: The phrase doesn't seem to have any relevance to the story you describe. Can you give more context? 'Recent stuff' could be 'things that happened recently', but I only know of the literal meaning of 'stocks of things'.

Comment: Well, that’s all the context that I know. Thank you for answer ;)

Comment: Maybe it was "stacks of things"?

Comment: Context needed.